# Unity Quaternions

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

Everyone tells me that I don't need to know what four separate parts of the quaternion mean in Unity. But I want to know it, the built-in methods in Unity don't solve some of my tasks. Tell me, please, where can I read about it?

Comment: [Google "Quaternion "](https://www.google.com/search?q=Quaternion) you can thank me later ^^

Comment: Yes, but I could not understand how a quaternion represtens rotation.

Comment: One of the first hits literally https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 parts, called w, x, y and z.

x, y and z represent a normalized vector in 3d space and are 3 imaginary components of the quaternion. x represents the x-axis etc.

The w component represents a rotation around the axis shown by the vector (x,y,z) in radians, anticlockwise, and is the real part of the number.

Quaternions exist in a system of mathematics where there are 3 imaginary numbers: i, j and k, each of which can be squared to get -1, and where ijk = -1 as well. w, x, y and z are real numbers, to create a Quaternion:

w + xi + yj + zk

These quaternions are multiplied to do rotations (the order of multiplication is important).

For practical purposes, you are unlikely to need to modify the components directly, it would often be simpler to do the calculations in Euler and then convert to Quaternion. It is good to know what they mean though, so here are some Wikipedia links (unity quaternions, are, at the end of the day, just normalized quaternions):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#:~:text=Unit%20quaternions%2C%20known%20as%20versors,rotation%20about%20an%20arbitrary%20axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#:%7E:text=Unit%20quaternions%2C%20known%20as%20versors,rotation%20about%20an%20arbitrary%20axis).

Answer (score 0):

Quaternion is a 4-dimensional complex number that consists of real and  imaginary parts. What is make Quaternion distinct form a Vector, is a special rules of multiplication that are applied to its imaginary parts.

Quaternions are representing the 4D unit sphere and is handy to calculate rotations in 3 spatial dimensions, here's the video that helped me a lot to understand how the math works in general: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjMuIxRvygQ

Also there is few simple practical hints:

1. Quaternion is a rotation itself, as the action. Imagine you have some orientation in space, it is your rotation now. Then turn to somewhere else, this is now your new rotation that is combination of the previous one and the amout of rotation you've just applied to yourself.
2. Quaternion can be combined (multiply one to another, the order matters!), interpolated and inverted.
3. 99% of the time you shouldn't mess with the underlying values of Quaternion (w,x,y,z) unless you're clearly understand what they mean and how they should be changed in order to get what you need.